# AngularJS select + multiple attribute and default angular option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the angularJS select directive with multiple value selected :

```
<select class="form-control genre-list" ng-model="filteredGenre" ng-options="g.name as (g.name + ' (' + g.moviesCount + ')') for g in genres" ng-change="filterGenre()" multiple>
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

associated with this in controller.js :

```
$scope.genres = [];
$scope.filteredGenre = [];
```

If I remove the multiple attribute, Default All option is present in my list and selected by default.

But with this "multiple" option I can see that All is briefly displayed before $scope.genres is setted with a list. After, this default option disapears.
The ng-multiple attribute is not working with an array datamodel (described in comments here [ng-multiple doc](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive%3angMultiple)

Did anyone already run into this conflict ?

Comment: Can you post Fiddle or Plunker?

Comment: Is `genres` populated with a delay? (E.g. from a server response). Because if not, I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsbin.com/AxANEqa/1/

Comment: @Yoshi, put $timeout or $http.get('some.json') :)

Comment: @MaximShoustin even with a fake delay and a properly initialised `genre` array, I can't reproduce it. http://jsbin.com/OsuTOHO/1/

Comment: Yes genres come from a $ressource call

Comment: @Yoshi yes but there no default value in your example. AngularJS doc say that there is a default value if no option selected by default.